Why is my query just returning O's instead of the percentages of the whole?
I attempted to divide to see the percentage each, medical practice provides of the data and nothing came out, just zeros in each row. enter image description here
I attempted to convert it into a BigInt to see if that was the problem. The data type for the column is tinyint, if that helps at all.
WITH CTE1(Specialty, Total_Instances) AS
(
    SELECT
        Specialty, COUNT(Severity) AS Total_Instances
    FROM
        MedMal85
    GROUP BY
        Specialty
)
SELECT
    SUM(Total_Instances) Total_Amount_of_Malpractice_Events
FROM 
    CTE1;

-- I want to see, the events per category next.

SELECT 
    Specialty, COUNT(Severity) AS Total_Events
FROM
    MedMal85
GROUP BY
    Specialty;

SELECT
    Specialty, COUNT(CONVERT(float, Severity)) / 158420 Percentage_of_Total_Events
FROM
    MedMal85
GROUP BY
    Specialty;


This question is similar to: How to get a float result by dividing two integer values using T-SQL?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It seems to me that there is something wrong with SELECT Specialty, COUNT(CONVERT(float, Severity)) / 158420 Percentage_of_Total_Events, probably the use of COUNT. Have a think about what needs to be counted and what ratio you want to find.

COUNT(CONVERT(float, Severity)) should be CONVERT(float, COUNT(Severity)) or just divide using a decimal 158420.0

count(column) just counts the non-null values, so converting the values in that column doesn't help. You need to convert the result of that count.
Or just divide by 158420.0

Maybe you have to cast the column to a rational datatype instead of bigint. If you use an integer type the decimals that occur when dividing would be removed. So 0.???? would become 0
EDIT:
If you use:
Count(Convert(float, Severity))/158420
You convert all entries of the severity column to floats and then count how many rows you have. But COUNT returns an integer. You need to switch the function calls so that the result of COUNT gets casted to float:
Convert(float, Count(Severity)) / 158420

So I just attempted to cast it to Float datatype and still got 0 for all my percentage results.
